# location counter overflow in tasm

Tags: assembly, tasm

i have this problem with an assembly file with 50K lines of code (it´s generated). I tried with model huge but the problem persists. Someone help me?

```
   *Warning* Libreria.asm(26227) Location counter overflow
   *Warning* Libreria.asm(52442) Location counter overflow
```

my code starts with

```
   .model small ; I tried with model huge but this does not work
   .stack 100h
   .data
      modovideo db ?
   .code
   main proc
      ; paint pixel by pixel - 150 000 lines , if this is less than 26227 lines, this works)
   main endp
   end main
```

Comment: What code do you see at/around lines 26227 and 52442 in your .asm file?

Comment: And what is your target system? 16, 32, 64 bit?

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that this is 16-bit code and that your code segment exceeds 64k. Huge model will not help, no segment in 16-bit mode can be larger then 64kbytes. Try to generate listing file and see if the offset in code segment wraps around (resets to 0) or goes beyond 65535 (0FFFFh).